# Getting error related to entity configuration when configuring a ValueObject in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, value-objects

When I am trying to add a migration, I get the following error:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'User.Email' of type 'Email'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

I don't want to use the `[NotMapped]` attribute, because I would like to create a column in my `Users` table. The existing answers I found on the internet were connected to many-many relationship or having collections of entities. I would like to configure the `Email` as a 'single' owned entity by the user, as far as I know using `OwnsOne` is the way to configure a value object.

Before the switching the `Email` to a value object, the add migration worked. Thank you for the help and let me know if you need more information.

The `User` class:

```cs
public class User : AggregateRoot, IAuditableEntity
{
    private User(Guid id, Email email, UserName userName) : base(id)
    {
        Email = email;
        UserName = userName;
    }

    private User()
    {
    }

    public ICollection<RolePermission> RolePermissions { get; set; }

    public UserName UserName { get; private set; }
    public Email Email { get; private set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOnUtc { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedOnUtc { get; set; }

    public static User Create(Guid id, Email email, UserName userName)
    {
        var user = new User(id, email, userName);
        return user;
    }

    public void ChangeName(UserName userName)
    {
        UserName = userName;
    }
}
```

The `Email` class (which is a value object):

```cs
public sealed class Email : ValueObject
{
    public const int MaxLength = 255;

    private Email(string value) => Value = value;

    private Email()
    {  
    }

    public static Result<Email> Create(string email) =>
        Result.Create(email)
            .Ensure(
                e => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e),
                DomainErrors.Email.Empty)
            .Ensure(
                e => e.Length <= MaxLength,
                DomainErrors.Email.TooLong)
            .Ensure(
                e => e.Split('@').Length == 2,
                DomainErrors.Email.InvalidFormat)
            .Map(e => new Email(e));

    public string Value { get; private set; }

    public override IEnumerable<object> GetAtomicValues()
    {
        yield return Value;
    }
}
```

The `DbContext`:

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Permission> Role { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
    : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(DbContext).Assembly);
    }
}
```

And finally the `UserConfiguration`:

```cs
public class UserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(TableNames.Users);
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.OwnsOne(x => x.Email);

        builder
            .Property(x => x.Email)
            .HasConversion(x => x.Value, v => Email.Create(v).Value);

        builder
            .Property(x => x.UserName)
            .HasConversion(x => x.Value, v => UserName.Create(v).Value)
            .HasMaxLength(100);

        //builder.HasIndex(c => c.Email).IsUnique();
    }
}
```

I tried to use `[ComplexType]` for the `Email` entity, it didn't make the migration work.

Comment: looking at the conversion functions you wrote, it more seems like you want `Email` to be a `string` in the database. Is that what you want? (p.s./side note remember that people could have multiple email addresses)

Comment: It also probably needs to be `.HasConversion(x => x.Value, v => Email.Create(v));`. Else the created type will be a string, not an `Email`.

Comment: There's no `ValueObject` in EF Core. You're trying to use DDD concepts from the business layer to DTOs at a different layer. You don't need a custom base object to [define value objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#simple-value-objects), only a conversion function. For more complex types, you can also use [owned entity types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities) which can be defined with just an `Owned` attribute.

Comment: Is `typeof(DbContext).Assembly` a typo? If not, it's telling EF to look into the EF Core package for application configurations. The code should be `typeof(ApplicationDbContext )`

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that for some reason none of the configurations were applied when I called the `ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly` method providing the assembly containing the dbcontext. So the the reason for this is still not clear. After applying the configurations one by one, it fixed the issue:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Permission> Role { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
    : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new UserConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new RoleConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new RolePermissionConfiguration());
    }
}
```

Comment: The `for some reason` is probably that those types are in different assemblies. If all configurations are in the same assembly, try `typeof(UserConfiguration).Assembly`. That's what [the documentation examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/#applying-all-configurations-in-an-assembly) show. It seems like you're trying to apply various "best practices" at the wrong level, or without understanding whether they're even good practices, resulting in far more complicated code than is necessary.

Comment: `modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(DbContext).Assembly)` is definitely wrong. This tells EF to look into the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll` for application configurations. It should be `typeof(ApplicationDbContext)` at least

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's no typo, the problem is :

```
modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(DbContext).Assembly);
```

This is telling EF to look for application type configurations in the assembly where the base class DbContext is defined, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll`.

At the very least, the code should be :

```
modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext ).Assembly);
```

or, better yet :

```
modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(UserConfiguration ).Assembly);
```

The second option would work even if the context and configurations were defined in different assemblies

Comment: great, thank you, it works.